# What arguments does Python sort() function have?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, key, python-2.x

Is there any other argument than `key`, for example: `value`?

Comment: well, does it work? and what exactly is it supposed to do.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

### Arguments of `sort` and `sorted`

Both `sort` and `sorted` have three keyword arguments: `cmp`, `key` and `reverse`.

```
L.sort(cmp=None, key=None, reverse=False) -- stable sort *IN PLACE*;
cmp(x, y) -> -1, 0, 1

sorted(iterable, cmp=None, key=None, reverse=False) --> new sorted list
```

Using `key` and `reverse` is preferred, because they work [much faster](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted) than an equivalent `cmp`.

`key` should be a function which takes an item and returns a value to compare and sort by. `reverse` allows to reverse sort order.

### Using `key` argument

You can use `operator.itemgetter` as a key argument to sort by second, third etc. item in a tuple.

#### Example

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter

>>> a = range(5)
>>> b = a[::-1]
>>> c = map(lambda x: chr(((x+3)%5)+97), a)
>>> sequence = zip(a,b,c)

# sort by first item in a tuple
>>> sorted(sequence, key = itemgetter(0))
[(0, 4, 'd'), (1, 3, 'e'), (2, 2, 'a'), (3, 1, 'b'), (4, 0, 'c')]

# sort by second item in a tuple
>>> sorted(sequence, key = itemgetter(1))
[(4, 0, 'c'), (3, 1, 'b'), (2, 2, 'a'), (1, 3, 'e'), (0, 4, 'd')]

# sort by third item in a tuple
>>> sorted(sequence, key = itemgetter(2))
[(2, 2, 'a'), (3, 1, 'b'), (4, 0, 'c'), (0, 4, 'd'), (1, 3, 'e')]
```

#### Explanation

Sequences can contain any objects, not even comparable, but if we can define a function which produces something we can compare for each of the items, we can pass this function in `key` argument to `sort` or `sorted`.

`itemgetter`, in particular, creates such a function that fetches the given item from its operand. An example from its documentation:

> After, `f=itemgetter(2)`, the call `f(r)` returns `r[2]`.

### Mini-benchmark, `key` vs `cmp`

Just out of curiosity, `key` and `cmp` performance compared, smaller is better:

```
>>> from timeit import Timer
>>> Timer(stmt="sorted(xs,key=itemgetter(1))",setup="from operator import itemgetter;xs=range(100);xs=zip(xs,xs);").timeit(300000)
6.7079150676727295
>>> Timer(stmt="sorted(xs,key=lambda x:x[1])",setup="xs=range(100);xs=zip(xs,xs);").timeit(300000)
11.609490871429443
>>> Timer(stmt="sorted(xs,cmp=lambda a,b: cmp(a[1],b[1]))",setup="xs=range(100);xs=zip(xs,xs);").timeit(300000)
22.335839986801147
```

So, sorting with `key` seems to be at least twice as fast as sorting with `cmp`. Using `itemgetter` instead of `lambda x: x[1]` makes sort even faster.

Comment: How can this work: `modNames.sort(key=lambda a: (a in data) and data.index(a))` (modNames, data are lists) ?

Comment: Well, items in `modNames` that are in `data` will be sorted as they are in `data` - items that are not will be assigned key 0 and sorted in the beginning of the list along with the first item in data that also has key 0.

Comment: Of note that `cmp` is deprecated in python3

Answer (score 3):

Besides `key=`, the `sort` method of lists in Python 2.x could alternatively take a `cmp=` argument (**not** a good idea, it's been removed in Python 3); with either or none of these two, you can always pass `reverse=True` to have the sort go downwards (instead of upwards as is the default, and which you can also request explicitly with `reverse=False` if you're really keen to do that for some reason).  I have no idea what that `value` argument you're mentioning is supposed to do.

Comment: He just said "value" as an (out of place here) example because he's seen "key" and "value" mentioned together.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it takes other arguments, but no `value`.

```
>>> print list.sort.__doc__
L.sort(cmp=None, key=None, reverse=False) -- stable sort *IN PLACE*;
cmp(x, y) -> -1, 0, 1
```

What would a `value` argument even mean?

Comment: `help()` is generally more useful than printing `__doc__` directly.

Comment: I usually use ipython, and there one can write just `list.sort?` instead of `help(list.sort)` to get help.