# Sort list of lists that each contain a dictionary

Tags: python

I have this list:

```
list_users= [[{'points': 9, 'values': 1, 'division': 1, 'user_id': 3}], [{'points': 3, 'values': 0, 'division': 1, 'user_id': 1}], [{'points': 2, 'values': 0, 'division': 1, 'user_id': 4}], [{'points': 9, 'values': 0, 'division': 1, 'user_id': 11}], [{'points': 3, 'values': 0, 'division': 1, 'user_id': 10}], [{'points': 100, 'values': 4, 'division': 1, 'user_id': 2}], [{'points': 77, 'values': 2, 'division': 1, 'user_id': 5}], [{'points': 88, 'values': 3, 'division': 1, 'user_id': 6}], [{'points': 66, 'values': 1, 'division': 1, 'user_id': 7}], [{'points': 2, 'values': 0, 'division': 1, 'user_id': 8}]]
```

I need to sort the list by points and values.

How can I sort it if dict is inside a list inside the main list?

I generated this list by query and than just append to `list_users`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What arguments does Python sort function have?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972672/what-arguments-does-python-sort-function-have)

Comment: You should _seriously_ consider rewriting the code that builds that list so that it produces a simple list of dicts. Having each of those dicts inside a one-element list is pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort using a [`key` function for `sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) that builds a tuple of `points` and `values` for each dict in each list.

```
def kf(x):
    return (x[0]["points"], x[0]["values"])
s = sorted(list_users, key=kf)
print(s)
```

Output:

```
[[{'division': 1, 'points': 2, 'user_id': 4, 'values': 0}],
 [{'division': 1, 'points': 2, 'user_id': 8, 'values': 0}],
 [{'division': 1, 'points': 3, 'user_id': 1, 'values': 0}],
 [{'division': 1, 'points': 3, 'user_id': 10, 'values': 0}],
 [{'division': 1, 'points': 9, 'user_id': 11, 'values': 0}],
 [{'division': 1, 'points': 9, 'user_id': 3, 'values': 1}],
 [{'division': 1, 'points': 66, 'user_id': 7, 'values': 1}],
 [{'division': 1, 'points': 77, 'user_id': 5, 'values': 2}],
 [{'division': 1, 'points': 88, 'user_id': 6, 'values': 3}],
 [{'division': 1, 'points': 100, 'user_id': 2, 'values': 4}]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Access the dictionary containing `points` and `values` by *indexing* on the inner list:

```
list_users_sorted = sorted(list_users, key=lambda x: (x[0]['points'], x[0]['values']))
#                                                       ^               ^
```

Comment: Is is possible to add a new field inside each position in dictionary?

Comment: In each dict add 'position': (number of position when is sorted)

Comment: Yes it is possible. Iterate through the sorted list using `enumerate` and for the dictionary in each  sublist, add a new key as `'position'` and the value as the index value from `enumerate`.